# how to downloading images from web server using AFNetworking in serial order

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, afnetworking

I am using **AFNetworking** to download json and images from the server in my app. I want to download the images in serial order using AFNetworking but the response is not in proper order as it gives images in random order. I have thumbnails in carousel on clicking i want to show bigger image of the same selected image but by using AFNetworking I am getting random images when i click on carousel image.

I can do the task using serial queues in GCD but I want to use AFNetworking to do the task. How to do it please suggest.

Below is my code for downloading in serial order using GCD

```
-(void)downloadImages:(NSMutableArray *)twitterThumbnailUrl withtwitterImages:(NSMutableArray *)twitterImageUrl
{
dispatch_queue_t queue;
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("myImageQueue", NULL);

    for(int i = 0; i<twitterThumbnailUrl.count; i++) {

        NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[twitterThumbnailUrl objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSURL *mainUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[twitterImageUrl objectAtIndex:i]];

        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            // do your stuff in the right order
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
            NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mainUrl];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            UIImage *mainImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            if (image != NULL) {
                [self.twitterImages addObject:image];
                NSLog(@"num = %d", i);
            }

            if (mainImage != NULL) {
                [self.celebImageArray addObject:mainImage];
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.carousel reloadData];
                [spinner stopAnimating];
            });
        });
    }

}
```

and below is the code using AFNetworking

```
-(void)downloadTwitterImages:(NSString *)twitterImagesUrl
{
    // download the photo
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:twitterImagesUrl]];
    AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation
                                          imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                          imageProcessingBlock:nil
                                          success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
                                          {

                                              if (image != nil) {

                                                  [self.celebImageArray addObject:image];
                                              }

                                              [self.carousel reloadData];

                                          } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                              NSLog(@"%@", error.description);

                                          }];

    [operation start];


}
```

How would I archieve the same in AFNetworking. Please help

UPDATE:

i tried this method from this post [link] and it's downloading images in order

this is my code. please correct me if I am doing anything wrong here

```
- (void) downloadTwitterImages:(NSMutableArray *)thumbnailArray {

    { 
        [_thumbDownloadQueue cancelAllOperations];
        _thumbDownloadQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        self.twitterImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    AFImageRequestOperation *previousOperation = nil;

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i<[thumbnailArray count]; i++) {

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[thumbnailArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
        AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation
                                              imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                              imageProcessingBlock:nil
                                              success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
                                              {
                                                  if (image != nil) {
                                                      NSLog(@"thumbnail downloaded %@", image);

                                                      [self.twitterImages addObject:image];
                                                  }

                                              } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                  NSLog(@"%@", error.description);

                                              }];

        if (previousOperation) {
            [operation addDependency:previousOperation];
        }
        previousOperation = operation;

        [_thumbDownloadQueue addOperation:operation];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code handling the image download completion doesn't use the index of the image URL. So, the resulting order is determined by the speed of each of the image downloads.

Consider something like setting up `celebImageArray` to be full of instances of `NSNull` and replacing each item when the associated image is received (using the index from the loop, which you would pass to the download method). Or, use a dictionary to store the image using the URL as the key so you can find the correct one later.

---

When you get the list of image URLs, do this:

```
self.celebImageArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (id url in self.twitterThumbnailUrl) {
    [self.celebImageArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
```

You now have an array with the items set to default values but all of the indexes are valid.

Instead of

```
[self.celebImageArray addObject:image];
```

You would have

```
[self.celebImageArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:image];
```

Which replaces the default items with the true items.

When you try to use the image on the cell you should check if it is an image and not `NSNull`:

```
if ([[self.celebImageArray objectAtIndex:index] isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
    cell.imageView.image = [self.celebImageArray objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: I can send index of the url to the download method but how to assign the same index to the image as image response coming randomly. could you help me with some code to archive this.

Comment: i am still not able to solve the problem with your method. could you provide some more code about how to do that. I have just added update to my post, it's working but i am still doubtful. thanks